# Oracle Number type without precision - how do I know if it is a whole number or not

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Our vendor's database has Number types for all numbers including whole numbers and decimal numbers. Literally, every numeric type column is created as NUMBER without precision and scale.

This is a big problem as we need to map these columns to proper data types on our target system, we are loading data from these tables into.

We need to know if a number is an integer or decimal.

Other than doing a random sampling/data profiling, is it possible to infer proper data types?

**UPDATE:**
I accepted the answer below and suggestion from @Bohemian. In addition to that, I will use SAMPLE clause that will do a random sampling of the table since my source tables are huge (many billions of rows).

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN col1 IS NOT NULL AND col1 <> round(col1, 0) then 1 else 0 end) as col1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN col2 IS NOT NULL AND col2 <> round(col2, 0) then 1 else 0 end) as col2
FROM TABLE
SAMPLE(0.05)
```

If I want to sample only X rows, use formula below to SAMPLE(N):

Xrows*100/table_rows_total

Comment: related discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921053/jooq-oracle-number-precision-and-java-number-mapping. JOOQ will be to BigDecimal in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try selecting each FIELD, and seeing if all values of FIELD are equal to ROUND(FIELD, 0).  If they are, then that field should be integer.  If not, decimal.

Comment: thanks, this is a clever idea! But it is similar to doing data profiling or sampling. wonder if there is metadata or statistics that can be used instead of doing hard pulls

Comment: If you are loading their DB into your own, then you should only need to "hard pull" the "test" once, which isn't (shouldn't?) be an issue.  Once you have the definitions of the fields, you wouldn't need to "figure them out" again, would you?  Or, if you are worried that the datatypes might change after a "first check", then whatever application you are using to pull the data can include a function to check each value as it's grabbed to make sure it "fits" with what you defined the field as on your side, and throw an exception if not.

Comment: `select sum(case when FIELD1 = round(FIELD1, 0) then 0 else 1 end) as FIELD1_NOT_INT_COUNT, (same for other fields) from mytable`. If you get zero, the column is always int.

Comment: I think this might be the best way but I will keep the question open for a few days to see if there is a better way.

Comment: I accepted the answer after spending a few hours researching. Looks like this is the best (unfortunately) option. I wish Oracle was more strict about data types.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered it [in this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043626/odp-net-oracle-decimal-number-precision-problem-when-filling-a-dataset-exceptio/60328164#60328164) and the query that you would use to find the maximum number of decimal places in all of the number columns is the same as that one.

To identify the columns with the their maximum decimal position digits, you can run the SQL below after substituting the MY_SCHEMA, MY_TABLE and the number 10 with say 25 to identify columns that have values over 25 decimal places. This SQL will generate a SQL that should be run to get your result.

```
SELECT 'SELECT ' || LISTAGG('MAX(LENGTH(TO_CHAR(ABS(' || column_name || ') - FLOOR(ABS(' || column_name || '))))) - 1  AS decimals_' || column_name || CHR(13)
                    , CHR(9)|| ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rn)  ||
                    ' FROM ' || owner || '.' || table_name  || CHR(13) ||
                    ' WHERE '  || CHR(13) ||
                      LISTAGG('(LENGTH(TO_CHAR(ABS(' || column_name || ') - FLOOR(ABS(' || column_name || ')))) - 1) > 10 ' || CHR(13)
                                , CHR(9)|| '  OR  ')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rn) AS Nasty_Numbers_Finder_Query
FROM
(
    SELECT  owner, table_name, column_name,
        row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY table_name  ORDER BY rownum) rn
    FROM  dba_tab_columns
    WHERE
        OWNER = 'MY_SCHEMA'
        AND table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
        AND (data_type LIKE '%FLOAT%'
            OR data_type LIKE '%NUMERIC%')
) a
GROUP BY owner, table_name
```

For more information, I have blogged about it [here](https://sqljana.wordpress.com/2020/02/20/oracle-odp-net-resolve-arithmetic-operation-resulted-in-an-overflow-or-specified-cast-is-not-valid/).